# Azure Data Factory: REST API Paging in Copy Activity

Tags: azure, api, pagination, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to do paging through copy activity in ADF. I have an api with base url https://xyz.xyz.com/v1/xyz-logs, this gets me the first page and the response JSON is like the below

```
{
"meta": {
        "count": 100,
        "total": 307,
        "cursorCount": 4
    },
"links": {
        "self": "/v1/xyz-logs?count=100",
        "first": "/v1/xyz-logs?count=100",
        "prev": "/v1/xyz-logs?after=12345&count=100",
        "next": "/v1/xyz-logs?before=12345&count=100"
    },
"data": [
           {data1},
           {data2}
        ]
}
```

In order to perform paging, I need to use the "next" value from the response.

How can I perform this using copy activity or any other method in ADF?

Kindly provide screenshots for the solution as it'll be easy for me to visualise and understand the solution.

Comment: Have you checked out the [official pagination support page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-rest?tabs=data-factory#pagination-support)?

Comment: I did, but it does not specify any solution for the problem I am facing. For them the full absolute URL itself is mentioned in the response. For me a part of the URL only is there. Kindly provide a solution for this!

Answer (score 1):

In your scenario next page link also consist of half part of base URL and half part of pagination URL. As per document there is no proper solution for this scenario and the example provided there is with the full absolute URL in next page link.

If your API response does not contain full absolute URL of next page, you can follow below workaround using **Until loop**:

- Set variable for the URL to store the URL value:
  [image]
- Then take a until loop and specify the condition as if URL variable is 'null' stop the iteration.
  **Expression:** `@equals(variables('url'),'null')`
  [image]
- Then inside until activity take Web activity and Copy activity to work on that API(For copy activity also you can use this URL variable in your source parameters)
  [image]
- After this take another set variable activity to update the URL as below:
  `@concat('https://www.ebi.ac.uk/ols/api/ontologies','?',split(activity('Web1').output._links.next.href,'?')[1])` here we are concating base URL with pagination URL.
  [image]
- After this on failure take another set variable to update the URL as 'null and stop the iteration.
  [image]

**This will paginate your URL.**

Comment: I try this solution, and while it works on small data sets, I run into the problem that for a large number of pages, at some point my authentication token expires.